# How to ungroup rows in Excel through scripts?

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I have to compare my application and the Excel downloaded from it. The rows are grouped in Excel.Is there a way to ungroup it through the scripts?

I am using Selenium Webdriver using Ruby.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to provide way more information.

Comment: I have to go through each and every cell of an Excel and compare it with a table in my application.But rows in the excel have been grouped on the basis of certain values.Hence i cannot view the entire data unless i click on '+' and ungroup the rows.How can i do that programatically?

Comment: What are you using to bring the Excel data into your program?  Are you reading an Excel file directly?  Interacting with the Excel spreadsheet real time in Excel?  Reading CSV?  Using a library such as Tika or the Ruby gem Rika to employ Tika to parse the Excel file using JRuby?